# How to use DataAdapter.Fill() asynchronously?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, asynchronous, ado.net

I have a DataAdapter that is filling 5 DataTables in a DataSet.

```
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from testTable",con);
da.Fill(ds, 0, numberOfRowsToPutInEachDataTable, "DT1");
da.Fill(ds, numberOfRowsToPutInEachDataTable , numberOfRowsToPutInEachDataTable , "DT2");
da.Fill(ds, numberOfRowsToPutInEachDataTable* 2, numberOfRowsToPutInEachDataTable, "DT3");
da.Fill(ds, numberOfRowsToPutInEachDataTable * 3, numberOfRowsToPutInEachDataTable, "DT4");
da.Fill(ds, numberOfRowsToPutInEachDataTable * 4, numberOfRowsToPutInEachDataTable, "DT5");
```

My goal is to get each

```
da.Fill...
```

to run asynchronously, at the same time.

I have no experience running things asynchronously and am having a hard time finding the solution through research. Can anyone show me how I can get each of these DataAdapter.Fill() to run asynchronously?

Comment: rather than putting some rows here and other rows there, you can load them all and use a DataView to show them in pages of 500 or whatever - if that is the reason for chopping them up

Comment: There are no asynchronous methods for `DataAdapter`. You'd be restricted to tasks although there are probably better ways to solve your problem.

Comment: Getting them to run at the same time is my only requirement.

Comment: @DavidL How could I achieve this using task?

Comment: @Reeggiie I'd recommend creating 5 separate, paged queries and executing them in separate adapters personally, spun up in new tasks.  Or even better, I'd get away from this type of thing altogether.

Comment: There is currently an effort to implement async functionality to DataAdapter.Fill in .NET at https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/22109

Answer (score 3):

You can use multiple threads of multiple `Task.Run()` this way:

```
Task.Run(() =>
{
    da1.Fill(ds.Table1);
    this.Invoke(new Action(() => {dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Table1;}));
});
Task.Run(() =>
{
    da2.Fill(ds.Table2);
    this.Invoke(new Action(() => {dataGridView2.DataSource = ds.Table2;}));
});
```

This way data will load using 2 different threads at the same time without freezing the form.

In above code, `da1.Fill` and `da2.Fill` will call in different threads at the same time. Since the code is executing a different thread than UI thread, to set the `DataSource` of `DataGridView` you should use `Invoke`.

Answer (score -1):

How about using [PLINQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997425(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from testTable", con);

IEnumerable<int> results = new string[]
{
    "DT1", "DT2", "DT3", "DT4", "DT5"
}
.AsParallel()
.Select((table, index) => da.Fill(ds, 
                          numberOfRowsToPutInEachDataTable * index, 
                          numberOfRowsToPutInEachDataTable, 
                          table));
```

---

## EDIT

The proposed solution is definitely not recommended.

It appears that [DataSet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset(v=vs.110).aspx) does not support concurrent write operations:

> This type is safe for multithreaded read operations. **You must synchronize any write operations**.

Comment: This runs without error but my 5 datatables are remaining empty at the end of this execution. Is there anything I need to change?

Comment: @Reeggiie See updated answer. DataSet does not support concurrent write access.