# Why doesn't System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter have a FillAsync method?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, ado.net

Naturally-asynchronous operations are not CPU bound and don't have a thread.  For example, file reads are done in the I/O hardware which can be kicked off asynchronously without a thread, enabling concurrency.  Whenever I come across resources that discuss this, they always use external-system-bound operations as examples, and they almost always have "like I/O or database operations".

ADO.NET has plenty of async methods, like `SqlCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync`, but one thing it doesn't have is `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter.FillAsync`.

Many resources covering this happily suggest that you just use `Task.Run`, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38797603/2704659) and [this one](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1121822/Using-Async-Await-Task-Methods-With-SQL-Queries-NE), e.g.:

```
public Task<DataSet> GetDataSetAsync
(string sConnectionString, string sSQL, params SqlParameter[] parameters)
{
    return Task.Run(() =>
    {
        using (var newConnection = new SqlConnection(sConnectionString))
        using (var mySQLAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sSQL, newConnection))
        {
            mySQLAdapter.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            if (parameters != null) mySQLAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddRange(parameters);

            DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();
            mySQLAdapter.Fill(myDataSet);
            return myDataSet;
        }
    });
}
```

But that code isn't truly asynchronous: there's still a thread.

So was it an intentional decision not to have `FillAsync`, and if so, why?

Comment: I suppose because this is legacy api. Most of them never got async upgrades. Because there are modern alternatives, like EF - which has async all the way around.